# Limit distribution of a supremum

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, X_2, · · ·$ be sequence of independent nonnegative random variables having a common distribution function $F$ such that $P(X_1=0)<1, E[X_1]=a<\infty$ and $\mathrm{Var}[X_1]=\sigma^2<\infty$. Let's denote $$S_0 = 0, S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots $ and $$N_t =\sup\left\{n:S_n ≤t\right\}$$ for any $t≥0$.

As $t\rightarrow\infty$ what is the limit distribution of
$$\frac{N_t-\frac{t}{a}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2t}{a^3}}}$$

I always had difficulties getting limit distributions and I get really confused. Can anyone lead me on this please? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the description of the tag '[distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)'?

Comment: I removed it, thanks. @md2perpe

Comment: Your notation isn't clear to me, what do you mean by $\sup\{n:S_n\leq t\}$?

Comment: @JingeonAn It's the supremum of n when $S_n \leq t$

Comment: But you know, $S_n$ is a random variable, not a real number, so do you mean $S_n(x)\leq t$ for all $x$, or what?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I'll post the answer later. @JingeonAn